# Programming language evolution vs underlying architecture

Tags: compiler-construction, architecture, programming-languages, emulation

Let's say we have a programming language `foo`. `foo` has a compiler for `System A` but not for `System B`. Now the `System B` developer can either write his/her own compiler for `foo` or write a `System A` emulator that runs on `System B` and can make use of the compiler written for `System A`. An obvious advantage of the emulator is that it's not limited to running the compiler and opens up `System B` to other `System A` specific programs. The obvious disadvantage in most cases is performance and complexity depending on the systems.

What I'm interested in finding out is which one of these approaches is easier to maintain. For example, let `php` be the language in question and lets assume that `phc` is the only compiler available for the language. This compiler only works on Unix-like environments. So the question is, is it easier to maintain a new compiler for Windows (e.g. `phc-win`)? or maintain a Unix-like environment that works on Windows (e.g. `Cygwin`)?

Comment: You can answer your question with science. **Try both approaches, maintain both for a long time, carefully record the amount of difficulty you have with maintenance, and publish your findings**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the System A instruction set, the emulator is easier to write and maintain.  But you always pay a performance penalty, so you have saved on engineering effort for a small number of people, by making the larger number of users less productive.

However, systems are not just instruction sets.  The application runs on a virtual machine consisting of the System A machine instructions it uses directly, and the System A OS calls it makes.   To run System A applications on system B, you have not only emulate system A instructions, but System A operating system calls.    And given the complexity of modern operating systems, this can be a very big effort.

The Linux WINE  (WINdows Emulator) does exactly this; this runs Windows binaries under Linux (in various forms).  WINE emulates Windows x86 instructions by virtue of running on x86 only Linux systems which means it lets the CPU do the instruction emulation work.  Then it emulates a lot of Windows OS calls.  Its a big program, under continuous development (for over a decade I think), and has to continually change just to keep up with changes in Windows that Microsoft makes.  And it still has a wish/bug list for things it does not do well.

While WINE does pretty well, the effort to build and maintain it are pretty big.  You don't see a lot of competition, which suggests that the effort is daunting.

I will note that building a compiler doesn't solve the OS emulation problem either; source code of the application may now compile to native System B instructions, but the OS calls it makes .... the compiler doesn't handle.   As compiler engineers, you solve the code portability problem by pushing the OS emulation problem on the application owners.  That's an easier problem: they only have emulate the aspects of the System A OS calls on which they depend; they don't have to emulate *every* aspect of those calls.

Comment: Good answer, also it may be possible, depending upon the compiler for System A, to use its intermediate byte code output as a starting point for the System B "code generator" meaning that the cost of implementing a full System B compiler is lower as it leverages a part of the System A compiler.